# PHP Creating Nested Array Dynamically

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, nested-loops

I am having trouble on how can I get the result of the nested array, it shows only one data per Branch, it should be show all Division per Branch.

```
$selectedBranches = ['1', '5'];
$selectedDivisions = ['1', '3', '5', '26', '27'];

$branch = \App\Branch::whereIn('BranchID', $selectedBranches)->get();
$division = \App\Division::whereIn('DivisionID', $selectedDivisions)->get();

for ($b = 0; $b < count($selectedBranches); $b++) {
    for ($c = 0; $c < count($selectedDivisions); $c++) {
        if ($branch[$b]->BranchID == $division[$c]->BranchID) {
            $branch_arr[$branch[$b]->BranchID] = array(
                $division[$c]->DivisionName
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Branch Query Result

| BranchID | BranchName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | BranchOne |
| 5 | BranchFive |

Division Query Result

| DivisionID | DivisionName | BranchID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Foo | 1 |
| 3 | Fooz | 1 |
| 5 | Rap | 1 |
| 26 | Bar | 5 |
| 27 | Barz | 5 |

Output

```
^ array:2 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▶
    0 => "Foo"
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▶
    0 => "Bar"
  ]
]
```

Expected Output

```
^ array:5 [▼
  1 => array:1 [▶
    0 => "Foo",
    1 => "Fooz",
    2 => "Rap",
  ]
  5 => array:1 [▶
    0 => "Bar",
    1 => "Barz",
  ]
]
```

Comment: Can you print the result of the DB query?
$branch = \App\Branch::whereIn('BranchID', $selectedBranches)->get();
$division = \App\Division::whereIn('DivisionID', $selectedDivisions)->get();

Comment: I just updated my post and added the result of each query. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $branch_arr = [];
    for ($b = 0; $b < count($selectedBranches); $b++) {
    $branch_arr[$branch[$b]['BranchID']] = [];
    for ($c = 0; $c < count($selectedDivisions); $c++) {
        if ($branch[$b]['BranchID'] == $division[$c]['BranchID']) {
            $branch_arr[$branch[$b]['BranchID']][] = array(
                $division[$c]['DivisionName']
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation and therefore is missing an opportunity to educate/empower the asker and thousands of future researchers.